# RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase

Tags: python, torch

I develop a code that performs neural network modelling using Pytorch. My code runs pretty well in my Pycharm console, but it does not work when I run it from a script. I checked it several times and I don't see any obvious problem.

The full error that I get is:

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

The error in my code seems to originate in my trainer (and more specifically in the last line i.e. in "val_split=0.1)":

```
trainer.fit(
        X_tab=X_tab,
        target=target,
        n_epochs=5,
        batch_size=256,
        val_split=0.1)
```

I use Python 3.7 and Windows, if that helps. Could that be a multi-processing problem or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

My understanding is that this has to do with the reduction.py backend code.

If anyone get this runtime error, you can add:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import code
    code
    code
```

and it will solve the issue!